# Особенности использования protobuf объектов в .net (C#) вместо нативных классов

Tags: c#, .net, grpc, google-protobuf

Правильно ли использовать protobuf классы вместо нативных (обычных) классов в C#, если это возможно. Допустим, у нас есть GRPC микросервис. Какой из вариантов по работе с данными будет предпочтительнее и почему.

Варианты:

1. Внутри микросервиса вся бизнес логика использует нативные классы C#, то есть обычные классы. Перед тем, как отдать результат по GRPC экземпляры обычных классов преобразуются в proto для отправки.
2. Другой вариант. Чтобы не делать лишних преобразований, то есть конвертирование обычных классов в proto, мы везде в приложении используем proto объекты. То есть везде вместо родных простых классов мы используем proto классы. Очевидно, что proto объекты более жирные чем обычные классы. Могут ли тут быть какие то подводные камни?

Comment: Объекты сериализуются в момент отправки, а пока вы их не отправляете, можете использоватьк как хотите. _Очевидно, что proto объекты более жирные чем обычные классы._ - как вы это поняли?

Comment: Я бы сформулировал несколько иначе. Когда используется protobuf? По моему, когда есть мультиплатформенный проект, и структура данных, общая для всех его частей. То есть, если Вы напрямую используете классы сгенерированные из протобафа, то Вам надо держать в голове, что вообще то они могут поменяться. То есть, это как бы внешняя зависимость. А над своими классами - у вас есть иллюзия полного контроля

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии. Отвечу по порядку.

Comment: 1) В процессе работы сервиса, создаются десятки тысяч объектов некоторого типа.Если заглянуть внутрь сгенерированного proto то можно увидеть кучу "служебных" полей и методов, необходимых для сереализации и т.д. По этому возникает вопрос, не будет ли оптимальнее в нутри бизнес логики работать с простыми классами. Как поведет себя GC с proto типами и насколько больше они займут RAM по сравнению с нативными.

Comment: 2) Хороший аргумент в пользу использования внутри сервиса обычных классов. Но конкретно в моем случае микросервис является "владельцем" или "эмитентом" proto контракта. То есть, если потребуется изменить proto объекты, то это будет сделано из за изменений в самом микросервисе. То есть исключена ситуация в которой есть несколько равноправных микросервисов разделяющих одну и туже модель данных. В моем случае, каждый сервис независим, а данные "стекаются" в сервис агрегатор, который является потребителем.

Comment: _proto объекты более жирные_ - насколько? как измерили? _кучу "служебных" полей_ - это сколько? Вы рассуждаете не используя факты. По потреблению памяти, есть профилирование памяти, никто не запрещает стартануть простой бенчмарк и измерить ответ на ваш вопрос. _Как поведет себя GC с proto типами_ - а какие есть варианты ответов? какое именно беспокойство вызвало данный вопрос? GC ведет себя со всеми типами совершенно одинаково. Более того, он их вообще не различает и про "типы" ничего не знает. _Могут ли тут быть какие то подводные камни?_ - кто вам даст гарантию, что не могут?